# Does bond yield always equal the prevailing bank interest rates?

Tags: bonds

Does a bond's yield (principal and coupon rate) always equal the bank interest rate?

Comment: There are several different bonds with numerically different yields, they cannot all equal "*the bank interest rate*". And what exactly do you mean by "*the bank interest rate*"?

Answer (score 1):

Each fixed income instrument has an interest rate implied by a transaction price, and these prices can move in different directions.

The FRED website has a list of some of the more important interest rates in the United States: 
[link to FRED.](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/22) However, these are mainly “generic” yields, which are based on fitting a curve through traded bond quotes. For example, the “10-year Treasury bond” yield shown on the website is going to be close to the the market yields of Treasury bonds/notes that are near a 10-year maturity, but there are spreads between them.